# How to make the navbar items clickable not the entire navbar itself

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to CSS and I'm trying to make my second website. My problem is that the entire navbar is clickable. The navbar items, on the other hand, is okay and it should have clickable fields.

The navbar should be set on the right side of the screen and it should display (portfolio, about me, contacts, and resume) from left to right.

I have tried messing the setting between "display: inline" and its padding to see if that fixed the issue but I'm still getting clickable fields around the entire navbar. I don't know how to fix this issue.

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.menu {
padding: 20px 8px;
margin: auto 0px;
color: #fff;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
list-style: none;
cursor: default;
text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline;
}

.menu a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #272727;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #272727;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Beta Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

   <nav class="main-nav">
      <a href="index.html"></a>
         <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="resources/stackoverflow.pdf">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#main-footer">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#about-me">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#projects">Portfolio</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, the fields around each of the navbar items should be clickable not the entire navbar section. I'm aware of the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5z9bgc6/) website but I'm trying not to alter my style too much because I might not like the end result.

[EDIT]
Here is the revised CSS code with minor changes:

CSS (New):

```
ul.menu {
padding: 20px 8px;
margin: auto 0px;
color: #fff;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
list-style: none;
cursor: default;
text-align: center;
float: right;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.menu a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #272727;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: Ok with @panther 's suggestion, I've edited the CSS code as such. I've added red border layers to see how "spaced out" are the clickable fields.

Comment: Perfect: now with @Noah's Baxley's suggestion, the clickable fields within the red borders are now gone.

Comment: Padding make the entire space clickable. Just change the `padding` property of the `.menu a` to `margin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding is clickable in anchors. Use margin instead. Display: inline-block is a mess when items are floated.

```
li a {margin: 15px; line-height: 40px;} /* just text clickable */
```

OR

```
li a {margin: 15px 0; padding: 0 15px; line-height: 40px;} /* text and left/right neighborhood clickable */
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jetgmshu/) to see the differents. 1st is your code, 2nd and 3rd are my variants used in the answer. Red background shows you what area is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

With a few suggestions from the community, the final CSS code is the following: (its the same as the [EDIT] version, but I'll post it here just in case)

```
ul.menu {
padding: 20px 8px;
margin: auto 0px;
color: #fff;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
list-style: none;
cursor: default;
text-align: center;
float: right;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.menu a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #272727;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have set the cursor to look like it's clickable.

```
ul.menu {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This will always make it look like it is clickable. Just get rid of that completely or use default instead.

```
ul.menu {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor) out to look at the different types of cursors

Comment: How this answer solves the question. Why does this answer suppose to be here?

Comment: Question isn't for cursor but for anchors. The second thing, the cursor will be still hand after your change, try it.

Comment: @panther is correct. Anchors were the main issue but it is now resolved.

Comment: The cursor type was being placed on the wrong thing though. If you remove the cursor type, the issue is fixed. There is multiple ways to solve this issue. My way worked on my machine maybe it works on yours.